# Vb.net multithreading not working...?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm trying to create a multithreaded program to poll machines for data but I can't seem to get it working correctly. The code below is working and is creating 4 threads as it should but the flow of the code seems to happen in series and on the main UI thread.

What I'm trying to achieve is for each row of the datagrid to update simultaneously without locking up the UI.

Below is a dumbed down version of what I have but it serves to demonstrate the problem.
For info the 'testclass' is a class used as an instance of a machine with each class element representing a property of a machine.

Hope I've given enough info to explain the problem. Thanks in advance.

Ps I shouldn't need to refresh form should I?

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class TestForm

Public threadcount As Integer
Public Delegate Sub testclassDelegate(test As Object)

Private Class testclass
    Public index As Integer
    Public TestVal1 As Integer = 100
    Public TestVal2 As Integer = 200
    Public TestVal3 As Integer = 300
    Public TestVal4 As Integer = 400
    Public TestVal5 As Integer = 500
    Public TestVal6 As Integer = 600
    Public testDel As testclassDelegate
End Class

Private Sub TestForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i As Integer = 0 To 3
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = i + 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To 3
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = ""
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = ""
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = ""
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = ""
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = ""
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = ""
    Next
    Poll_FreeThread()
End Sub

Private Sub Poll_FreeThread()
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim test As New testclass
        test.index = i
        test.testDel = AddressOf UIUpdate

        Interlocked.Increment(threadcount)
        Me.Label2.Text = threadcount
        Try
            Dim thPoll As New Thread(Sub() invokeUIUpdate(test))
            thPoll.IsBackground = True
            thPoll.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
            thPoll.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub invokeUIUpdate(test As Object)
    If DataGridView1.InvokeRequired Then
        DataGridView1.Invoke(New testclassDelegate(AddressOf UIUpdate), test)
    Else
        UIUpdate(test)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub UIUpdate(test As Object)
    Thread.Sleep(test.index * 100)
    DataGridView1.Rows(test.index).Cells(1).Value = test.TestVal1
    Me.Refresh()
    Thread.Sleep(100)
    DataGridView1.Rows(test.index).Cells(2).Value = test.TestVal2
    Me.Refresh()
    Thread.Sleep(100)
    DataGridView1.Rows(test.index).Cells(3).Value = test.TestVal3
    Me.Refresh()
    Thread.Sleep(100)
    DataGridView1.Rows(test.index).Cells(4).Value = test.TestVal4
    Me.Refresh()
    Thread.Sleep(100)
    DataGridView1.Rows(test.index).Cells(5).Value = test.TestVal5
    Me.Refresh()
    Thread.Sleep(100)
    DataGridView1.Rows(test.index).Cells(6).Value = test.TestVal6
    Me.Refresh()
    Interlocked.Decrement(threadcount)
    Me.Label2.Text = threadcount
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hint: Set a breakpoint on `invokeUIUpdate` and see what happens to the `if`.

Comment: 1. Did you check with _Me.InvokeRequired_ instead of _DataGridView1.InvokeRequired_ ? 2. Also, there is no need to call _Me.Refresh()_ after setting every cell value, you can place it just once after setting last cell value.

Comment: Thanks Raymond. That had crossed my mind but alas it wasn't running the else condition if that's what you meant?

Comment: just tried your suggestion Coder and same result... The reason I had the refresh after each entry is to see it being written real time but I reckon if this was working as it should there would be no need for refresh at all.

Comment: Exactly. You start a background thread. Then you call `InvokeRequired` which asks, "Am I on a background thread?" The answer is always Yes, so you call `Invoke`, which means "Switch to the UI thread." So you went to an awful lot of trouble and ended up back where you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your code a little bit different, This is how the Structure should look like for Multithreading in vb.net ( it has something to do with Vb.net not passing Namespaces into Models from what i Understand )

**This would be your startThread from MainThread in load or w/e have you**

```
Private Sub DoSomethingSimple()
    Dim DoSomethingSimple_Thread As New Thread(AddressOf DoSimple)
    DoSomethingSimple_Thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
    DoSomethingSimple_Thread.Start(Me)
End Sub
```

**This would be the actual thread Itself ( new model / class or in the same class )**

```
Private Sub DoSimple(beginform As Form)
    'Do whatever you are doing that has nothing to do with ui

    'For UI calls use the following
    SomethingInvoked(PassibleVariable, beginform)

End Sub
```

**Write a Delegate and Invoke Method for Each Call to the Main Thread.**

```
Delegate Sub SomethingInvoked_Delegate(s As Integer, beginform As Form)
Sub SomethingInvoked_Invoke(ByVal s As Integer, beginform As Form)
    If beginform.NameOfControlYouAreUpdating.InvokeRequired Then ' change NameOfControlYouAreUpdating to the Name of Control on the form you wish to update
        Dim d As New SomethingInvoked_Delegate(AddressOf SomethingInvoked_Invoke)
        beginform.Invoke(d, New Object() {s, beginform})
    Else

        'Do something...
        beginform.NameOfControlYouAreUpdating.Condition = Parameter

    End If
End Sub
```

This is tested ( non hanging ) way of writing Threads in vb.net

If you need further help implementing your code to this Template let me know :P

Answer (score -1):

You can use timer and backgroundworker with event of DoWorkEventHandler and RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler.

Example: C# example:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
workerThreadForLetters.WorkerReportsProgress = true;                    workerThreadForLetters.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
workerThreadForLetters.DoWork -= new DoWorkEventHandler(workerThreadForLetters_DoWork);
workerThreadForLetters.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(workerThreadForLetters_DoWork);

workerThreadForLetters.RunWorkerCompleted -= new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(workerThreadForLetters_RunWorkerCompleted);

workerThreadForLetters.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(workerThreadForLetters_RunWorkerCompleted);
}
    private void workerThreadForLetters_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
               //DO SOMETHING
    }
    private void workerThreadForLetters_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
             //DO AS REQUIRED
             Timer1.enable = false;
    }
    private void tmCollectionLettersUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             //Content update like % of data progressed or any.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and excuse my ignorance but am I not limited to one background worker? Ultimately I will be polling up to 100 machines simultaneously in a continuous loop so I'm not sure if bgworker will work in this case??

Comment: You could launch as many backgroundworkers as you want - but it is not a good solution. I think a threadpool might be more appropiate. This is theoretical knowledge, so I do not provide code - sorry. But you should consider using only a few threads, depending on the resource consumption of your threads.

Comment: Hi Christian. I have actually coded two options in my solution, one using a threadpool and one using unlimited threads for testing later with many machines to see how far I can push it. My problem is that I need a quick turnaround when polling the machines but the program will be running continuously on a dedicated machine so I would assume it would be ok to push it since there won't be any other requirements of that machine. This is all new territory for me though so I'm open to any advice!